# config:push is not a heroku command. Perhaps you meant config. How to solve?

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli, heroku-api

When I am typing :

```
heroku config:push
```

I am getting error as

```
config:push is not a heroku command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant config
 ▸    Run heroku help config for a list of available
 ▸    topics.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: If you are trying to push. Use heroku push .  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: What makes you think `config:push` is a command? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install the plugin:
heroku plugins:install heroku-config

More information on the official repository:
https://github.com/xavdid/heroku-config